# Node JS: JWT verify vs redis query performance comparison?

Tags: node.js, redis, jwt

I have implemented JWT token for authentication to my API which is served using node.js.

On every request sent to the server, I do a `jwt.verify()` but I'm wondering if this is more CPU intensive and therefore less scalable than storing the token in Redis, and retrieving the userId.

Example:

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const app = require('express')

app.get('/user',(req, res) => {
   const { headers: { authorization } } = req
   let token = null
   if (authorization && authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
     token = authorization.split(' ')[1]
   }
   jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
      if(err || !decoded){
         return res.json({success: false, message: `Not valid token`})
      }
      //
      // Continue with my logic
      //
   })
})
```

So I'm wondering if anyone knows if it's better performance-wise to do `jwt.verify()` vs a `redis.get()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's a subject to debate on but the answer heavily depends on what goals you are trying to achieve / which hardware do you use / how you plan to scale (as you have mentioned scalability)

**TL;DR** I would stick with `jwt.verify()` if it doesn't cause performance issues with your current load

1. For regular JWT token created with HS256 Algorithm, `jwt.verify()` is not a CPU intensive task that runs under <1ms on the modern CPU
2. For a Redis case we need to take into account two cases

   - We run a Redis instance on the same machine so we don't have to make a network call and lose time on latency or deal with the risk of the network error. But we anyway introduce a latency because 2 separate processes have to talk to each other but it would be the same <1ms
   - We have one global Redis server/cluster which stores our JWT tokens and we have to deal with network stuff and increase latency up to 30-50ms and even more
3. Also when we introduce Redis to our system we create an additional layer of the complexity to our system which has to maintained and etc.

*Regardless* of the fact that Redis brings an extra level of complexity, it's more Node.js-oriented philosophy to make everything async as much as we can and don't lock the CPU (EventLoop) with heavy tasks.

**BUT** using the Redis approach, we are *kind of losing* the advantages of the JWT itself (us userId already encrypted in token), and maybe we need to look at the solution which uses sessions to store userId instead of JWT. In most cases, we need to store JWT somewhere when the token becomes expired and we need to access the refresh token to create a new JWT.

So, I think that the best way would be to stick with `jwt.verify()` if it doesn't cause performance issues with your current load (like your server is not used at peak level all the time but that's another issue and topic to discuss)

P. S. You can use Node APIs like `process.hrtime()` to simply measure performance of your running code